# Qt app deployment for Linux

Tags: c++, linux, deployment, qt5

I made an app on Ot/X11. It works for me just fine but not for other Linux systems. It has something to do with libs and plugins. And the size for libs and plugins is about 400+ MB. how do I give them to others?

Answer (score 1):

build qt statically using the configure tool, link your app against these.

Comment: ..or create a package (rpm or deb or so..) and set appropriate dependencies in it. After all, this is what package management systems were intended for.

Comment: Yeah, I do not see the point of statically linking either. Although, even the question is unclear to me what exactly is causing issues and what Sanchit is trying to do that is troublesome.